# How to change links from wordpress themes and plugins folders from http to https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

We set up ssl on our blog, and have changed the site and homeurl settings from http to https in Admin, but it seems this only affected wordpress content(uploads) folder, links to the theme's and plugin's stylesheets still reference http instead of https, as a result the site is messed up, I've looked into the theme's header file, but found nothing to change there. How do I rectify this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress generates full absolute links for media you add via the editor because everything else would assume things about the location of the website (you can't use relative URLs because the blog might be at a subpath and historically the path itself is never saved)

[Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) might be what you're looking for. It allows you to replace certain phrases in database tables. You should make absolutely sure to not do a search-replace for `http` -> `https`since links that are already `https` will end up as `httpss`. Instead try searching for `http://` and replacing `https://`.

You should also consider setting up HSTS.

Comment: Thanks. I added this to my wp-config file and that solved the problem : 'if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';'   Found that on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75921/ssl-breaks-wordpress-css